# Question about double integrale and Fubini's theorem

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

> Question, Am I right about what I state down here:

---

I want to find the Laplace transform, of an integral:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-\text{s}t}\left\{\int_0^\infty\text{y}\left(t,\text{x}\right)\space\text{d}\text{x}\right\}\space\text{d}t$$

So, in general I am studying the double integral:

$$\mathcal{I}\left(\text{s}\right)=\int_0^\infty\text{f}\left(\text{s},t\right)\left\{\int_0^\infty\text{y}\left(t,\text{x}\right)\space\text{d}\text{x}\right\}\space\text{d}t=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\text{f}\left(\text{s},t\right)\text{y}\left(t,\text{x}\right)\space\text{d}\text{x}\space\text{d}t$$

In order to switch the order of integration, we can apply Fubini's theorem:

$$\color{red}{\mathcal{I}\left(\text{s}\right)=\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\text{f}\left(\text{s},t\right)\text{y}\left(t,\text{x}\right)\space\text{d}t\space\text{d}\text{x}}$$

The red part is equal when:

$$\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty\left|\text{f}\left(\text{s},t\right)\text{y}\left(t,\text{x}\right)\right|\space\text{d}\text{x}\space\text{d}t\space<\text{n}\to\infty$$

But when I look at [this website][1], they only talk about when the integral equals a definite value, and my integral contains the variable $\text{s}$, how do I deal with that?

[1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem

Comment: Given $F(x,t)$ you can change order of integration provided that one of associated repeated integral of $|F|$ exists (that is, $F$ is measurable and the integral is finite) and repeated integral equals integral over product measure space. Your function containing $s$ doesn't really have any effect unless for some $s$ the integral turns out to be inifnite, $s$ can be considered constant as it is not variable being integrated